# Why I get unhandled exceptions while I'm using DataAnnotation Validation in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, exception, data-annotations

I have a form that reads from viewmodel
I added required data annotations to viewmodel properties 
Below is the post action method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult actionName(TestViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

                var testObj = new TestModel
                {
                  //mapping
                };

                db.TestModel.Add(testObj);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(vm);
        }
    }
```

I submitted the form with no values, to test data annotations validation,
but instead of getting red error messages, I see the yellow screen of death with unhandled exception (System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null)

Shouldn't data annotations handle this?

I don't want to get an error page added through web.config for this. 
I need normal error messages to show below input fields

Comment: please checked with debug your action of `ModelState.IsValid` what contains data into this and in `vm`

Comment: True, I had errors unhandled by foolproof library